# What is a clean way to select one of multiple options in Angular UI?

Tags: angular

Example UI: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mt4vgt?file=src/app/app.component.ts

What is a clean way to select one of multiple options in Angular? The way I do it in the above app involves a lot of code duplication.

For each of the 3 buttons in the app, I have to have a method that does the below:

```
  btn1Clicked() {
    this.isBtn1Selected = true;
    this.isBtn2Selected = false;
    this.isBtn3Selected = false;
  }
```

And then based on which button is selected, I style the button using ngClass.

And when the `Next` button is clicked, I perform an action based on which option is currently selected. What is a clean way to do all of this?

**Note:** If it is relevant, in the real app, the options buttons are replaced with Angular material cards `<mat-card>`, but besides the HTML tag, the rest of code is the same as the buttons in the above Stackblitz app.

Comment: how about an array and using ngFor to loop your buttons?

Comment: what about radio buttons instead of buttons, then use css to style them?

Comment: @JasonWhite As mentioned in the Note, the buttons are actually material cards in the real app.
And I'm not sure how to implement the ngFor or the radios for my purposes.

Comment: Here is an example of radio buttons that might work for you.  You could replace the inner content of the `<label>` with your `mat-card`'s.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dxpc2x?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: You could try render your btn with ngFor and then use the index to get the "selected" value: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jqsrkr